# What is the negation of the test "is"?

Tags: c#

To test if an object is of a certain type then we write `if ( myObject is SomeClassName )`

But how do we write if I want to test that the object is not of the mentionned type ?

Comment: `if (! myObject is SomeClassName)` ?

Comment: `if(!x is y)`...

Comment: `if (!(myObject is SomeClassName))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!(myObject is SomeClassName))
```

Is probably the cleanest way of checking not is. Just checks if it is the type of object then flips it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one, you have to wrap it in a ! operator:

```
if (!(myObject is SomeClassName))
```